# Pass Hashtable by reference to Winform; usage of this variable in BGW not updating originally passed hashtable when canceling BGW

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to pass a hashtable to a winform and use a backgroundworker to add some values to the hashtable. If I cancel the BGW operation the hashtable should be back to its original values (i.e. before the BGW was started).

With the below code SomeHashtable returns from the BGW with the values added before canceling even though I try to reset it to its original state in RunWorkerCompleted when canceling. I need help in understanding the issue here and how to implement the reset correctly.

I prepared a short sample below with a form that has two buttons on it ("add" and "cancel").

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim SomeHashtable As New Hashtable()
    SomeHashtable.Add(-1, -1)

    Dim dlgAdd As New frmFileAdd(SomeHashtable)
    dlgAdd.ShowDialog()

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(SomeHashtable.Count) 'if user cancels BGW this should be 1 (-1,-1)
End Sub
End Module

Public Class frmFileAdd
    Private SomeHashtableForm As Hashtable = Nothing
    Private SomeHashtableInit As Hashtable = Nothing


    Public Sub New(ByRef _SomeHashtable As Hashtable)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        SomeHashtableForm = _SomeHashtable 

        SomeHashtableInit = SomeHashtableForm.Clone() 'shallow copy to reset SomeHashtable to its initial values if i cancel the BGW


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        bgwAdd.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        If bgwAdd.IsBusy() And Not bgwAdd.CancellationPending Then
            bgwAdd.CancelAsync()
        Else
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub bgwAdd_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwAdd.DoWork

        For iRun = 0 To 9
            If Not bgwAdd.CancellationPending Then
                SomeHashtableForm.Add(iRun, iRun)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)

            Else
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgwAddFiles_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwAdd.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Cancelled Then
            SomeHashtableForm = SomeHashtableInit 'I was expecting that this will also affect the ByRef _SomeHashtable variable used in the constructor but it is not
            'SomeHashtableForm = New Hashtable(SomeHashtableInit) i also tried this
            Me.Close()

        Else
            'Do something else
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: First things first, get rid of the `ByRef` on that constructor parameter. The fact that you think that's a good thing to do demonstrates that you don't understand how value types and reference types and passing by value and reference actually work. You should stop what you're doing and learn about that first.

Comment: Second things second, don't use a `Hashtable`. That type has been obsolete since 2005, when the `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) ` was introduced. If you would use a `List(Of T)` rather than an `ArrayList` - I really hope you would - then don't use a `Hashtable`.

Comment: I do understand that if reference types are passed ByVal then changes in my method calls would still show on these variables. At least this is how I understand it. I used ByRef because I thought this could be required since i am changing the reference itself in my code when resetting the variable to its original values.

Comment: But you're not changing the reference itself. The reference is `_SomeHashtable`. Where are you assigning anything to that? You're not. What's more, as I said, you absolutely shouldn't be. DO NOT pass constructor parameters by reference. They should ONLY ever be inout.

Comment: Okay thanks I will change it. But what I don't understand is that I am working with SomeHashtableForm and changes to it will show in _SomeHashtable. So then why is this line "SomeHashtableForm = SomeHashtableInit" not affecting _SomeHashtable as well?

Comment: For one thing, `_SomeHashtable` no longer exists by that stage, because the constructor finished executing some time ago. Secondly, `_SomeHashtable` and `SomeHashtableForm` are references that initially refer to the same object but you then assign a different object to one of them. Why should that affect the other? Let's say that I have a bike and I decide to share it with you: `You.Bike = Me.Bike`. Later on, you get a new bike: `You.Bike = New Bike()`. Does that suddenly mean that I have that new bike too? Of course not. Setting `You.Bike` has no effect on `Me.Bike`. Same thing here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I alluded to in my comments, it's clear that you don't really understand how value types and reference types or passing by value and by reference actually work. Here:

```vb
Public Sub New(ByRef _SomeHashtable As Hashtable)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    SomeHashtableForm = _SomeHashtable 

    SomeHashtableInit = SomeHashtableForm.Clone() 'shallow copy to reset SomeHashtable to its initial values if i cancel the BGW


End Sub
```

That `ByRef` is of no use at all. The only way pass a reference type (class) by reference is useful is if you assign a different object to that parameter inside the that method. You don't assign anything to the parameter in that constructor so declaring it `ByRef` is pointless. Further, you ABSOLUTELY should NEVER declare a constructor parameter `ByRef`. The purpose of a constructor is to construct and object, not pass data out.

Here:

```vb
If e.Cancelled Then
    SomeHashtableForm = SomeHashtableInit
```

all you're doing is assigning one field of the form to another. That has exactly zero effect on anything outside the form. Both fields are private and are not exposed in any way so they cannot be accessed from outside the form.

Exactly what you should do is up for debate, because there's definitely not just one thing you could do. I would suggest that what you should do is not touch the original dictionary at all until the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Only at that point should you populate the original dictionary, if and only if the work wasn't cancelled. That might look like this:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim data As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) From {{-1, -1}}

        Using dialogue As New Form1(data)
            If dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation completed. Item count = {data.Count}")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation cancelled. Item count = {data.Count}")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private data As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    Public Sub New(data As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Me.data = data
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim tempData As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

        For i = 0 To 9
            If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Return
            End If

            tempData.Add(i, i)
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next

        e.Result = tempData
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Cancelled Then
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        Else
            Dim tempData = DirectCast(e.Result, Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))

            For Each kvp In tempData
                data.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
            Next

            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

In this case, the data is added to a completely separate `Dictionary` and is only transferred to the original when the work completes without being cancelled. Just be aware that, in a real situation, that might mean that you end up with duplicate keys. To avoid that, you ought to check the original `Dictionary` before adding to the temporary one:

```vb
If data.ContainsKey(i) Then
    'This key can't be added to the original data so decide what to do about it.
Else
    tempData.Add(i, i)
End If
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and it works fine. More importantly now I understand why my approach did NOT work in the first place.